# Визуализация графов для теории автоматов

Tags: c#, c++, gui, графы

Подскажите библиотеки/классы, для визуализации графов.
IDE **QT5** или **VS 2017**. Язык **С++** или **С#**.
Задача: реализовать задачи по теории автоматов для десктопа.
Иметь возможность создавать/удалять вершины, ребра. Двигать вершины.

Comment: Визуализация в десктоп приложении для C# - WPF

Comment: да, программа для десктопа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе не указано, насколько сложные могут быть графы

**Опыт**

Делал похожий курсовой на delphi - задать граф, нарисовать и выделить на нём кратчайший путь. Делал всё сам - Метод draw принимал матрицу инцидентности и рисовал граф. На форме можно сделать контрол для редактирования этой матрицы, в моём случае использовался файл с заданным форматированием.

Ещё недавно рисовал треугольник - небольшая фишка была в масштабируемости, т.к. треугольник должен был помещаться в заданной области. Использовал такой подход:

1. maxLengh = getMaxSide(triangleSides) самая длинная сторона треугольника
2. baseLength = 200 максимальная длина стороны, которую могу нарисовать
3. scale = maxLength / baseLength коэффицент, то во сколько раз нужно увеличить 
   каждую сторону, чтобы сохранить пропорции треугольника
4. drawSides = map(triangleSides, side => side * scale) каждую сторону треугольника умножить на scale, в результате получатся стороны треугольника, которые гарантированно поместятся в области.

**Обзор**

Готового api редактора графа нету, зато есть несколько вариантов для визуализации графов - т.е. просто нарисовать, есть библиотека для работы с графами. Возможно придётся отказаться от идеи с перетаскиванием узлов. Я бы использовал `graphx + quickgraph` - ссылки ниже. Самый простой вариант -  сделать отдельно рисование, редактирование графа реализовать через редактирование матрицы инцидетности.

**Альтернативы**

- Python - сам не пробовал, но слышал, хорош в рисовании графиков
- d3js + fabricjs - сделать всё на канвасе в браузере, относительно легко получить по-настоящему крутой редактор. d3js - библиотека для создания маппинга данных на графику, рисовал с его помощью простые графики. fabricjs - редактирование на канвасе, делал с его помощью редактирование картинок на сайте. Если использовать их вместе, то можно написать свой редактор графов с перетаскиванием и любыми фичами, которые захочется добавить, например, выделить одновременно несколько узлов и перетащить, или удалять рёбра по клику. Используя electron, можно даже сделать десктопное приложение.

**Библиотеки для визуализации**

- https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=graphx мой выбор
- https://github.com/komorra/NodeEditorWinforms может быть пригодится
- https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=graphsharp
- https://github.com/JamieDixon/GraphViz-C-Sharp-Wrapper генерирует
  картинку, которую можно отображать в контроле, самый простой

**Библиотека для работы с графами**

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=quickgraph

**Готовый проект, который похож на требования**

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562829/Building-an-oriented-graph-in-a-graphical-applicat

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересно, на QT написал программу для рисования графов. Исходный код на [github.com/fryn3/elasticnodes](https://github.com/fryn3/elasticnodes). И это в разработке [github.com/fryn3/widGraph](https://github.com/fryn3/widGraph).